# preg_match pattern where a specific character should not come before another

Tags: php, regex

I'm extracting some image-urls from a website.
For that purpose I'm using this regex:

```
preg_match_all('#"(http.*?jpg)"#', $html, $matches);
```

However that will give a wrong result on lines like these:

```
<a href="http://omg.com/test.html"><img src="http://omg.com/image.jpg"></a>
```

I cannot search for `<img` tag because some images come from javascript.

But what is definite is that all the images is enclosed by two  `""`

So what would solve my problem is to change my regex to not allow any `"` characters between "http" and "jpg"

Something like this in pseudocode

```
preg_match_all('#"(http.?:(anything except ")?jpg)"#', $html, $matches);
```

How do you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use negation in your regex to make sure to not to match `"` between `http` and `jpg`:

```
preg_match_all('#"(http[^"]*jpg)"#i', $html, $matches);
```

**[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hH8dE5/2)**

As a word of caution though parsing HTML using regex is not the best way to scrap the web pages. You may consider using `DOM` parser.

Comment: dont think i can use any finished dom parser, alot of the images come from javascript with no tags, only images encased in "" inside functions

Comment: Ok no issues that was just a suggestion. My regex should work for you.

Comment: +1 But you don't need the lazy modifier - its only slowing things down a wee-bit in this case.

Comment: Thanks, yes its not really needed. Corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below regex which uses a negated character class.

```
"(http[^<>]*jpg)"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yC6oN7/2)

`[^<>]*` this ensures that there isn't a `<` or `>` symbols  present in between the `http` and `jpg` strings.